# Aes Encryption not working

Tags: c#

I have no idea whats going wrong here. Everything works fine and it loads, but the 'encrypted' data is the same as the original data. No encryption had been done.

```
if (entry.type == stype.file)
{
    aes.IV = aes.Key; //for now just testing..
    byte[] startData = File.ReadAllBytes(baseDir + entries[i]);
    aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV).TransformFinalBlock(startData, 
                                                             0, 
                                                             startData.Length);
    entry.data = startData;
    entry.data_size = (ulong)entry.data.LongLength;
    ulong eSize = (ulong)(29 + (ulong)entry.name.Length + entry.data_size);
    total_size += eSize;
    entry.entry_size = eSize;
}
```

`entry.data` is the same as the original startData. Is `TransformFinalBlock` not encrypting the `startData`?

Comment: aes.Key is a random 256 generated key btw

Answer (score 3):

`TransformFinalBlock` returns the data, it doesn't encrypt the input inplace.

Comment: Yeah thanks! I was coding C++ so long and I was used to pointers '&' etc. so I just assumed it would encrypt startData as a ref. :p

Comment: Does `TransformFinalBlock` actually do proper encryption, assuming the input is less than a block?

Comment: @Rawling Only using `TransformFinalBlock` is fine, as long as you can fit the message into memory. You only need `TransformBlock` for long streaming encryption/decryption. Despite the `Block` in their name they're not related to blockcipher blocks.

Comment: @Codes OK, thanks. I've only ever used the stream methods to transform so I'm a bit suspicious of something as simple as encrypting an array :)